# Why does getch() in c not work on my mac os x?

Tags: c, getch

I use mac OS X Yosemite. Getchar() works fine, but getch() does not work.
It says "Implicit declaration of function 'getch' is invalid in C99.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `getch()` is stnadard `C`. `getchar() ` **is** the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`getch()` is declared in `conio.h` which is not part of the Standard C Library.

From Wikipedia:

> conio.h is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide
>   console input/output. It is not part of the C standard library or
>   ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX.

Comment: ok, so How can I get the header file?

Comment: Check your compiler manual.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/myconio/